# JavaScript timer works only once + bootstrap 3 modals

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, timer

everybody! I am a JavaScript novice.

I am making an online test, where questions are popping up several times during the test. Every question must have a timer. Unfortunately, my timer works only during the first question.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="timer">10</button>
```

Here is my timer():

```
function timer(){
    var obj=document.getElementById('timer');
    obj.innerHTML--;

    if(obj.innerHTML<=3){
        $('#timer').removeClass("btn-default");
        $('#timer').addClass("btn-danger");
    }

    if(obj.innerHTML==0){
        $('#myModalTest').modal('hide');
        setTimeout(function(){},1000);
        play();
    }
    else{setTimeout(timer,1000);}
}
```

Here is how my questions pop up:

```
$("#start").click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        pause();
        $('.test1').modal('show');
        setTimeout(timer,1000);
    }, 10000);      
});

$("#continue1").click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        pause();
        $('.test2').modal('show');
        setTimeout(timer,1000);
    }, 10000);
});
```

On .test2 timer is always 10 and doesn't work.

Also I am wondering how to make next question pop up, if a user hadn't clicked anything and timer has come to 0, and a modal has hidden.

Thank you for your time and attention.

Comment: Your code has some basic flaws starting off with `obj.innerHTML--;` and `obj.innerHTML==0` These make no sense as you are treating them like a numeric global number which they are NOT.  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML  In addition, you should show some markup related to this question as well as the code for `play()`, `pause();` etc.  You hide two modals but show anther in the "timer" function which seems like a logic flaw in this limited code set.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce your issue in this [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/loresuworu/edit?html,js,console,output) and I'm not sure if what I did was what you wanted. Try it and give me feedback.

I think that your issue was here:

```
function timer(){

    if(obj.innerHTML==0){
      ...
    }
    else{setTimeout(timer,1000);} // here 
}
```

if `obj.innerHTML !== 0` is going to call `timer` each second, and this can be closing each pop up you open... but i'm not sure because I don't have all the code.